# Powershell script to publish APIM developer portal

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-api-management

I am planning to publish the developer portal using powershell but i am unable to do that.
team please help me anyone [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**: This functionality is a part of service API now: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2021-01-01-preview/portal-revision/create-or-update

**Previous answer below**:

I do not believe that this part is documented yet, but to publish dev portal you need to:

1. Use Get SAS token API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2019-12-01/user/getsharedaccesstoken) to get token for user with ID 1, i.e.
2. Publish portal by sending following request:

```
POST https://<service-name>.developer.azure-api.net/publish
Authorization: SharedAccessSignature <token-you-obtained-on-step-1>
```

Comment: Is the below syntax correct or do I need to make any changes to it?                                      ```                                                                                                                                        curl -v -X POST https://apim-demo-apim.developer.azure-api.net/publish  -H "Authorization: SharedAccessSignature  <SAS token> " -H  "Content-Length: 0"                                                                       
 ``` Coz I get HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized  response.